# Initialize an `io.StringIO` with invalid unicode, so that `.readlines` fails?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

Is it possible to initialize an `io.StringIO` (or equivalent) with an invalid UTF-8 string, such that it fails on calling `readlines()`? I know this is a weird request, but I'm trying to reproduce a failure mode in a unit test.

Currently, I am trying to read a text file, and accidentially got a binary file. My code crashes with

> builtins.UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte

I would like to reproduce this in a test case, and then fix this (catch the UnicodeDecodeError and then report that the file is invalid). However, I don't want to keep a copy of the invalid file among my test cases. I think it should be possible to create a File-like object that behaves like my invalid File instance.

I've tried

```
f = io.BytesIO(b'\x89')
myfunction(f)
```

but that doesn't work since reading from f returns `bytes` objects. I need something that tries to return `str` (unicode). I can't use something like

```
f = io.StringIO('\x89')
myfunction(f)
```

because that fails already before calling myfunction. Any ideas?

---

My current workaround is:

```
import listingparser
import unittest
import io

class ListingParserTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_invalid_input(self):
        """ Invalid file contents should cause ParseError, not UnicodeDecodeError. """
        with open('test-temp.dat', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(b'\x89')
        with open('test-temp.dat', 'r') as invalid_file:
            with self.assertRaises(listingparser.ParseError):
                listingparser.parsef(invalid_file)
```

but I'd like to do the same - creating a booby-trapped `invalid_file` object - without temporary file. The following doesn't count :-), I feel it needs to know too much about the internals of `parsef`:

```
class MockFile(object):
    def readlines(self):
        raise ParseError()
```

Comment: 0x89? Choked on a PNG?

Answer (score 1):

> However, I don't want to keep a copy of the invalid file among my test cases.

Why not? It's a test case.

```
>>> import codecs,io
>>> f=codecs.EncodedFile(io.BytesIO(b'\x89'), 'utf-8')
>>> f.readlines()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```